# Optimised code for computing truncated weighted sum of matrix products

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, numpy, sum, matrix-multiplication

I need to perform a double sum over a weighted matrix product like this: [mathematical expression of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhNzk.gif)
where C is a list containing some different weights (complex) for each term and 
X are an 3d-array where the index refers to the i'ths 2d-array along the depth axis. I need to evaluate a sum of such expression thousands of times (different 'm' arrays) so the execution time is very important. in the real problem the arrays are of greater dimensions. An illustrative minimum example of my code is

```
import numpy as np
from time import clock
X = np.random.random((12,12,31))
m = np.random.random((12,12))
C = list(map(lambda x: x*2+1j*x, range(31)))

def summing(m):
    start = clock()
    t2 = np.zeros((12,12),dtype = complex)
    for i in range(len(C)):
        for j in range(len(C)):
            t2 += C[i]*(X[:,:,i].dot(m).dot(np.conj(X[:,:,j].T)))                  
    return t2, clock()-start
summing(m)[1]
```

The execution time for me is around 0.025s, which is way too slow for the number of computations I need to perform. Running in parallel is not an option as this function is part of a larger parallel computation, so parallelising this would create nested parallel computations.
Do any of you see a much cleverer way of performing this computation in a faster and hopefully a more pythonic way?